# Replacing references of MSXML4 with MSXML6. Is namespace MSXML2?

Tags: c#, .net, msxml, msxml6, msxml4

Getting some odd build behavior as I remove all references to MSXML4 in my project, and replace them with MSXML6.

When I install MSXML using NuGet, or if I add it manually by referencing the dll in `SysWow64`, the reference immediately builds down to `Interop.MSXML**2**.dll` in my solution folder > obj > release.

The properties of the reference indicate it's version 6, but I don't have confidence as to which version is actually being used -- in large part because of the naming convention.

Do all versions MSXML compile into this `interop.msxml2` file? It appears as though the namespace is `MSXML2`, but the naming convention is odd here.

Comment: `MSXML2` is the logical name of the library that resides in `msxml6.dll`. You can verify that it's version 6 by the fact that `DOMDocument60` is available. I don't see why you would need to use `MSXML2` from .NET though.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Very old platform, but it's legacy--I'm just tasked with changing versions.

Comment: See also this question that discusses MSXML4 and MSXML6 and upgrading to MSXML6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075891/what-became-of-msxml-4-0 as an answer or two has some additional information about various MSXML versions.

Comment: What nuget package delivers MSXML? I can't find any... thanks

Comment: It’s going back a couple years...I’m fairly certain I manually downloaded it, installed it into that legacy application, and checked it into git...because that’s what they were already doing.