# Msxml3 - Memory leak

Tags: msxml, msxml3

I plan to write an application (win32 platform) for parsing the xml documents. For parsing the xml's, i plan to use the msxml3.dll (microsoft latest service pack library) but many forum described that this has an huge memory leak issue.

Is this really true that msxml3.dll has huge memory leak?

Comment: Any particular reason why you're not able to use MSXML6?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951804/which-version-of-msxml-should-i-use - i.e. don't use MSXML3 unless you need to support ancient OS's.

Comment: I have to write my application to suport for Win2k. So, i plan to use msxml3.dll

Answer (score 4):

MSXML3 has its own garbage collection mechanism. If you don't know about this mechanism, MSXML3 only "appears" to be leaking memory before garbage collector kicks in and recycles resources. Please check [Understanding the MSXML garbage collection mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304227) for more details.