# Calling WCF service with parameters from VBScript

Tags: wcf, vbscript

**[Calling WCF service by VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944975)**

I'm trying to use the code from the above stack article, but my WCF service method requires parameters:

SaveCheckData int,int,string,string

I've tried frigging with the code to incorporate this, but to be honest, I may as well be trying to perform heart surgery.

Can anyone shed any light on how i'd need to modify the code to call a SOAPAction that requires parameters?

Thanks

Mick

Comment: Any luck with this answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call WCF (.svc) service from VBScript, WScript, VBA, etc with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455075/call-wcf-svc-service-from-vbscript-wscript-vba-etc-with-parameters)