# how do i call web service methods using VBScript?

Tags: web-services, vbscript, wsdl

I have WSDL service running on my machine and it has few methods

GetResources()
GetCounters() 
etc i want to get data from those methods.
How can i do that using VB Script.
Can anyone just help me out in doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling WCF service by VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944975/calling-wcf-service-by-vbscript)